# Wordpress returns a wrong date

Tags: php, date, date-time

I am trying to get the todays date , day and time .

**Today is : 10th july 2018,tuesday and time is 3.23am**

For time the below code works fine:

```
$wpplcurrenttime = current_time( 'g:i a', $gmt = 0 );
echo $wpplcurrenttime;
```

and out put is: 3.23 am which is correct

But strangely the date is not getting correct :
the **returned date is 9th july 2018,Monday**

These are the codes i tried :

```
$dw = date('l');
echo $dw;
echo date(get_option('date_format'));
echo date('l jS F Y');
echo gmdate('w');
```

All of above codes gives a wrong date and day. 
I have double checked the WordPress general setting it is showing the date and time correctly.

Really appreciate the help
Thanks

Comment: WordPress internal time is on GMT timezone. then if you want to use "date", "mktime" or "strtotime", you have to change the timezone with https://secure.php.net/date_default_timezone_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mmm said, wp stores all dates&times in gmt, but will show times as per the setting timezone. So you can cgange the timezone without the history needing to be updated. 
I prefer to use the php [datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)  when working with time.  Gives better control and flexibility, eg if you want to show events in different users timezones, let the system deal with daylight saving etc.

To Fetch the wp timezone and create tz object, then use

```
$tzs = get_option('timezone_string');
$tzobj = timezone_open($tzs);
```

To create datetime object for 'now' in a particular timezone

```
$now = date_create('now',$tzobj );
```

to format dates & times, use any format accepted by [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
echo date_format($now, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: i am having some troubles with get_option('timezone_string'); https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/308238/how-to-check-foe-wordpress-timezone-type

Comment: Possibly the site is using the old gmt offset (less good since it doest cope wiuth daylight saving). If no timezonestring found, use 

$gmt_offset = get_option ('gmt_offset')  and deal with the offset